# OAuth 2.0 with PKCE for Twitter with R

Tags: r, twitter, oauth-2.0

I would like to post "Hello World" in Twitter using R. I´m using a Free Acount and it seems than now I must use OAuth 2.0 with PKCE.

I have a Client_id, client_secret, api_key, api_secret, access_token and access_secret created and use rtweet, but with this new type of OAuth 2.0 with PKCE I don't know how to do it.

Someone can explain me how to post "Hello World" in twitter using R with this kind of OAuth 2.0 with PKCE?

Thanks

Comment: Authentication (for a "user access token") should also work with OAuth 1.0a: [https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a) in case you are already familiar with that process.